# ListFragment "Content view not yet created" after detach attach

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I'm new in android programming.
I tried ListFragment populated from database, and it works well.
I could display the values, but when I try to refresh the view by detaching and attaching the fragment again, got error content view not yet created on getListView() which I put on onActivityCreated.
Any ideas?

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
  listView = getListView();

  db = new DatabaseAccess(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
  List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();

  if (contacts.size() > 0) {
    List<Map<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    for (Contact con : contacts) {
      Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>(2);
      data.put("name", con.getName());
      data.put("number", con.getNumber());
      contactList.add(data);
    }
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getView().getContext(), contactList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, new String[] {"name", "number"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
  } else {
    setEmptyText("Masih belum ada kontak");
  }
  setListShown(true);
  db.closeDB();
}
```

when I try to refresh the fragment

```
void refreshFragment() {
  Fragment frg = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
  FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  fragTransaction.detach(frg);
  fragTransaction.attach(frg);
  fragTransaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: Yes, don't refresh a fragment by using detach, attach. Do findFragment, check if the fragment is the correct instance and call a refresh function which will just update the content.

Comment: @Raanan : thanks, but please do explain about "check if the fragment is the correct instance" as in how to do that?

Comment: if(fragment instanceof MyFragment) {... }  before you cast it to MyFragment, exactly how you did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize:

1. Attach/Detach isn't a correct way of refreshing the view
2. find the Fragment and call a refresh function to update the content
3. setListShow - doesn't need to be called, the list is by default invisible until a call to setAdapter is made - then if there is content it will become visible.
4. Call the setListAdapter also if the adapter is empty.

To refresh the list you don't need to recreate everything just update the adapter content and call the invalidateDataSet function.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got something right (I think) based on suggestion by @Raanan which is making a function to populate the list and can be called when needed.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
  listView = getListView();
  populateList(listView);
}

void populateList(ListView lv) {
  db = new DatabaseAccess(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
  List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();

  if (contacts.size() > 0) {
    List<Map<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    for (Contact con : contacts) {
      Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>(2);
      data.put("name", con.getName());
      data.put("number", con.getNumber());
      contactList.add(data);
    }
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getView().getContext(), contactList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, new String[] {"name", "number"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
  } else {
    setEmptyText("Masih belum ada kontak");
  }
  setListShown(true);
  db.closeDB();
}
```

and the refresh method is

```
void refreshFragment() {
  Fragment frg = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
  if (frg instanceof ScreenContact) {
    ((ScreenContact) frg).populateList(((ScreenContact) frg).getListView());
  }
}
```

ScreenContact is my fragment class derived from ListFragment. but still when the data is empty, I still can't show the "setEmptyText" like when the app's first time running.

Comment: it is because you are calling setListShown(true); outside of the if.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html#setListShown(boolean)  -  Applications do not normally need to use this themselves.

Comment: if I'm not using this setListShown(true) the progress animation keep on spinning and not showing the empty text nor the data (if available)

Comment: I created an answer.